# C# - Passing 3 parameters vs passing object with 30 properties -

Tags: c#, performance, function, memory-management, parameters

I was wondering, which way is better in terms of performance and memory usage?

Passing only the needed parameters for a specific function or its the same to pass an object with 30 properties but the function will use 3 of them?

Comment: If your function only uses 3 variables, why pass everything? Do something about your design, instead of worrying about performance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not decide this on the basis of performance. The performance difference is so minimal to be negligible. (But to answer your question, passing the object is faster if it’s a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx); passing the parameters is faster if the large object is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).)

You should decide this on the basis of **what your code means.** If the method is logically related to the object with 30 properties, then it makes sense for the method to take the object. You might also want to think about whether any *future changes* to the method might need access to more of the properties.

If the method is logically unrelated to the object, and the three values you pass in are just pieces of information for the method, you should pass them in as separate parameters. You should also think about whether any *future code calling the method* may want to pass in *different* values than those three properties from that specific object.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I would greatly appreciate further elaboration on your point regarding the method being logically related to the method and the opposite. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you call any non in lined method, the variables you pass as arguments will actually be physically copied to the formal parameter slot memory in the called method. This causes stack memory operations and incurs a performance hit. It is faster to minimize arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends if you are passing it by value or reference.
Typical parameters (int, float, double, bool) are all passed by value. Means they are copied.
If you pass object it only "sends" pointer to object (reference) to function which is 4 or 8 bytes long.

It is more efficient to pass object if you have that many parameters.

Answer (score 0):

if it is local operation that pass object is better, because it is reference only. But if you want to pass object through network that your object will be whole serialized and will be great size

Answer (score 0):

That may depend on many factors...

- For example whether the 3 properties are reference type or value type - C# is "pass by value" language, which for value types copies the whole object during each assignment or argument passing, but for reference types it only copies the reference, not the whole object.
- Performance would be almost the same (again the only difference is copying the values/references), unless some of the properties are for example lazily evaluated/created

In general, minimizing method arguments is "a good thing", but may impose dependencies, so it's more about your data structures and code.

Also remember that usually performance is one of the least important code metrics, so avoid premature optimizations and focus more on what the code means, how readable and maintainable it is. If you have performance issues, I doubt this would ever be the bottleneck.